# Page Speed google is showing Style.css in render blocking

Tags: php, wordpress, google-pagespeed

Can any one know how to remove style.css from render blocking in word press.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me give brief about the render blocking files.

See WordPress site has a theme and plugins that add JavaScript and CSS files to the front-end of your website which can increase your site’s page load time.

When browser loads page it load those scripts and CSS before loading rest of the HTML on the page. These scripts and stylesheets are called as render-blocking JavaScript/CSS.

Solution:

> You can install and activate the Autoptimize plugin. You can refer
>   it's installation [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/#installation). This plugin gives option to optimize
>   JS/CSS code. After activation, you need to visit the Settings »
>   Autoptimize page to configure the plugin settings.
>
> Then test your website using PageSpeed tool. If there are still render
>   blocking scripts, then visit plugin’s settings page again and click on
>   ‘Show Advanced Settings’, here you allow plugin to include inline JS
>   and remove scripts that are excluded by default. And then retest your
>   site using PageSpeed.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use any plugin. I want to do it manually. can you please guide me, what if I load all the scripts in to footer that would resolve my issue?

Comment: to be clear; the autoptimized CSS will be default also be render blocking, but the next step is to either "inline all CSS" (easy) or "inline & defer CSS" (better). more info in AO's FAQ; https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/#faq